# grails maven dependency resolution

Tags: plugins, grails, groovy, dependency-management, xerces

I have a grails plugin with following BuildCofnig.groovy

```
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {

    }

    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    repositories {
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        flatDir name: 'lib', dirs: "${userHome}/libs"
    }

    dependencies {

        runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.9')

        compile('net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:4.0.1') {
            excludes 'antlr', 'commons-beanutils', 'commons-collections', 'commons-logging',
                     'ant', 'mondrian', 'commons-javaflow', 'barbecue', 'xml-apis-ext', 'xml-apis', 'xalan', 'groovy', 'groovy-all', 'hibernate', 'saaj-api', 'servlet-api',
                     'xercesImpl', 'xmlParserAPIs', 'spring-core', 'bsh', 'spring-beans', 'jaxen', 'barcode4j', 'batik-svg-dom', 'batik-xml', 'batik-awt-util', 'batik-dom',
                     'batik-css', 'batik-gvt', 'batik-script', 'batik-svggen', 'batik-util', 'batik-bridge', 'persistence-api', 'jdtcore', 'bcmail-jdk14', 'bcprov-jdk14', 'bctsp-jdk14'
        }
        compile('vomsws:VomsWsClient:1.0')
        compile('com.jaxfront:jaxfront-core:1.0',
                'com.jaxfront:jaxfront-html:1.0')
        compile('freemarker:freemarker:2.3.8')
        compile('org.apache.poi:poi:3.6')
        compile('commons-net:commons-net:3.0')
        compile('commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1')
    }
}
```

I can pacakge plugin successfully. However when I import this plugin in a fresh Grails project and try to do run-app. I get following exception stack tace:

```
  [groovyc] Compiling 452 source files to C:\Users\Alam Sher\.grails\1.3.2\projects\witribe-test-gui\plugin-classes
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/xni/parser/XMLParseException
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:116)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure4_closure10.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:118)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure4_closure10.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:282)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure4.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:105)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:68)
    at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure9.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:84)
    at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure9.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:282)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
    at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:83)
    at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:28)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:115)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/xni/parser/XMLParseException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureClassNode(Java5.java:313)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.checkCyclicInheritence(ResolveVisitor.java:1269)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1246)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavaAwareCompilationUnit$1.call(JavaAwareCompilationUnit.java:63)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:931)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:509)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:487)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:464)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:448)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.compile(FileSystemCompiler.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.doCompilation(FileSystemCompiler.java:170)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.compile(Groovyc.java:830)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.execute(Groovyc.java:552)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParseException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:156)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:128)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 43 more
--- Nested Exception ---
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/xni/parser/XMLParseException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureClassNode(Java5.java:313)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.checkCyclicInheritence(ResolveVisitor.java:1269)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1246)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavaAwareCompilationUnit$1.call(JavaAwareCompilationUnit.java:63)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:931)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:509)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:487)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:464)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:448)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.compile(FileSystemCompiler.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.doCompilation(FileSystemCompiler.java:170)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.compile(Groovyc.java:830)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.execute(Groovyc.java:552)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure4_closure10.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:118)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure4_closure10.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:282)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure4.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:105)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:68)
    at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure9.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:84)
    at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure9.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:282)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
    at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:83)
    at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:28)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:115)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParseException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:156)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:128)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 43 more
Compilation error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/xni/parser/XMLParseException
```

Kind of lost what's the problem here.. Frankly speaking I'm new to this dependency management using Maven and have no clue what so ever.

Your suggestions, recommendations are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I see the number of exclusion you set, one should certainly correspond to the class not found .... Search for the good one ;-)

Comment: It didn't actually. I removed xercesImpl and xmlParserAPI from exclusions and still had to define a compile time dependency in the new grails project which imported this plugin to work right. Can't understand what caused this though and this is ugly to have such explicit xerces compile time dependency in the grails project.

Comment: It worked later on and I forgot to accept your answer. Doing it now :)